# Backup & restore of data Like organization chart

Tags: database, organizational-chart

I have a database that every username should Enter some information in system & his (Admin,Admin User) then his (Admin) should give those Update Information to his (Users).

Now, I have some Problems to solve this & need your help

1. This program offline & there is no network.
2. The (Users) shouldn’t have all database & they have just information about themselves
   This like organization chart that each user can just access to his information.
   I want to know, how can I do backup & restore this information? In which way?
   Do you Know any software that can Restore?

[image]